# Prometheus cluster resource usage excluding master node

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm currently trying to get an idea of cluster k8s cluster usage with prometheus. We have a master that runs critical services. For the sake of the resource usage, I would like to exclude the master. We will often see clusters at 80% CPU/mem usage but with lots of pending pods because all worker nodes are full and master nodes are tainted.

Using mem as an example, I have the following query to get the cluster usage:

```
1 - sum(avg_over_time(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{container="node-exporter"}[10m]))
/ sum(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes)
```

I know what the master node instance label is with the following query:

```
$ leader_election_master_status{name="kube-scheduler"}

leader_election_master_status{endpoint="http-metrics", instance="172.20.62.250:10251", [...]}
```

I would like to query from the sums of node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes and node_memory_MemTotal_bytes that don't match the label `instance="172.20.62.250:10251"`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using the unless operator [1] and the label_replace function. I needed label replace because the instance labels had the same IP but different ports e.g. `172.20.62.250:10251` for the election master status but `172.20.62.250:9100` for the mem available. Here is the full query:

```
sum by (instance) (label_replace(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes, "instance", "$1", "instance", "(.*):.*"))
unless
sum by (instance) (label_replace(leader_election_master_status{name="kube-scheduler"}, "instance", "$1", "instance", "(.*):.*"))
```

[1] https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/

[2] https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/